# restart all api on RTF using an shell script

Tags: shell, mule, anypoint-rtf

i am trying to restart apis on Mule RTF using a script, but unable to login even, can anyone help?

below is the script :

```
#! /bin/bash

authToken=`curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"username":"username","password":"password","recaptcha":""}' https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/login/`
curl  "https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/login/=$authToken"
```

Comment: Why do you need to restart all applications deployed on your RTF instance?

Comment: to update patch

Comment: And how you did change the patch version for each application? You need to update it explicitly according to the documentation. Just restarting would not change the release.